# Setter Injection with Unity for ActionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, unity-container

Hi I use [MS Unity Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202) with my MVC 3 application.

I want to use setter injection to inject a dependency for Action filter. I have an action filter which I am registering in global.asax and this action Filter calls a repository class to load some data. I want to inject concrete class using DI. It can be very [easily achieved with StructureMap](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/03/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-filters/). But somehow I can't get it working with Unity. I have tried all solutions from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515028/setter-property-injection-in-unity-without-attributes).

Here is my code:

MyActionFilter.cs

```
public class GlobalViewBagActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public IUserRepo UserRepo { get; set; }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var testVal = UserRepo.LoadData();
    }
}
```

Registering Action Filter in Global.asax.cs

```
private static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new GlobalViewBagActionFilter());
    }
```

calling the above method on Appliation_Start to register

```
RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

I have tried many possible code block for registering the class but nothing worked. Either I would get an exception or on the action filter, UserRepo property would be null.

Any pointers on how do i get it working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the container:

```
private static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    var container = new UnityContainer()
       .RegisterType<IUserRepo, UserRepoImpl>()

       .RegisterType<GlobalViewBagActionFilter>(
           new InjectionProperty("UserRepo", new ResolvedParameter<IUserRepo>()) 
       );


    filters.Add(container.Resolve<GlobalViewBagActionFilter>());
}
```